# javascript: Calculate difference between two dates

Tags: javascript

I want to find difference between two Dates. For that I did subtract one Date object from another Date object. My code is as follows :

```
var d1 = new Date(); //"now"
var d2 = new Date(2012,3,17); // before one year
document.write("</br>Currrent date : "+d1);
document.write("</br>Other Date : "+d2);
document.write("</br>Difference : "+new Date(Math.abs(d1-d2)));
```

But the result is not as I expected:

**Currrent date : Sun Feb 17 2013 02:58:16 GMT-0500 (EST) 

Other Date : Sat Jan 21 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

Difference : Thu Jan 28 1971 21:58:16 GMT-0500 (EST)**

I want to calculate the (1 year) difference between them.

Thanks

Comment: And the result of your calculation has to be what? Days? Seconds? Years?

Comment: I want to calculate days,months and years since that date...

Comment: Then it gets tricky :) So you want to have something like "2 years, 5 months and 23 days since ..."?

Comment: yes I want to do some thing like that.

Comment: Don't reinvent wheels, use a library, e.g. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So fundamentally the biggest exact date unit is a **week** which accounts for 7 * 86400 seconds. Months and Years are not exaclty defined. So assuming you want to say "1 Month ago" if the two dates are e.g. `5.1.2013` and `5.2.2013` or `5.2.2013` and `5.3.2013`. And saying "1 Month and 1 day ago" if you have e.g. `5.1.2013` and `6.2.2013`, then you would have to use a calculation like this:

```js
// dateFrom and dateTo have to be "Date" instances, and to has to be later/bigger than from.
function dateDiff(dateFrom, dateTo) {
  var from = {
    d: dateFrom.getDate(),
    m: dateFrom.getMonth() + 1,
    y: dateFrom.getFullYear()
  };

  var to = {
    d: dateTo.getDate(),
    m: dateTo.getMonth() + 1,
    y: dateTo.getFullYear()
  };

  var daysFebruary = to.y % 4 != 0 || (to.y % 100 == 0 && to.y % 400 != 0)? 28 : 29;
  var daysInMonths = [0, 31, daysFebruary, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

  if (to.d < from.d) {
    to.d   += daysInMonths[parseInt(to.m)];
    from.m += 1;
  }
  if (to.m < from.m) {
    to.m   += 12;
    from.y += 1;
  }

  return {
    days:   to.d - from.d,
    months: to.m - from.m,
    years:  to.y - from.y
  };
}
// Difference from 1 June 2016 to now
console.log(dateDiff(new Date(2016,5,1), new Date()));
```

As I said, it gets tricky ;)

Comment: @Exception, what's a simpler alternative? Looks as small as possible given the leap year and variable days-in-month.

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 4):

If you need to be fairly accurate I suggest using days as your unit.  Years have a variable number of days so do months, so saying "1 month" or "1 year" can mean different #s of days.

```
var d1 = new Date(); //"now"
var d2 = new Date(2012,3,17); // before one year
var msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24;
document.write( ((d1 - d2) / msPerDay).toFixed(0) + " days ago");
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/V7ESF/)?

```
 Math.ceil((new Date(2012, 11, 23) - new Date(2012, 11, 21)) / 86400000) + 1
```

Comment: The difference in date objects is a difference in milliseconds. The divisor `86400000` presumes a fixed number of days per year, which is not strictly correct, I think.

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe 86400000 milliseconds equivalent to one day. So the  logic is correct

Comment: Makes sense. So this will calculate a number of days. The OP isn't clear, but he's looking for "2 years, 7 months, 22 days". That's what makes the problem challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

Math.ceil((new Date(2012, 11, 23) - new Date(2012, 11, 21)) / 864000) + 1