# Timer with a prefixed date - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have implemented a timer counter with a given starting date. Everything is normal until the point in which I want it to show months/days/minutes/seconds. I see where it lacks logic in my code, so my question is: Is there an elegant way to deal with that (the division of the total seconds), or should I just go with nested endless if statements?

```js
var deadline = "December 18 2016 08:00:00 GMT+0300";

function getTimeRemaining(endTime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) % 30 );
    var months = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24*30) );

    return {
        'total': t,
        'months': months,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}
```

Comment: `Date.parse(new Date())` is redundant (and error prone), use `new Date()`. You seem to want to calculate the difference between two dates in months, days, etc. Unfortunately months are of different lengths so simple division isn't accurate. There are many questions here already (most with bad answers), but there are some worth reading, e.g. [*Calculate difference between two dates*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919201/javascript-calculate-difference-between-two-dates).